# Python 3: Issue importing subpackages to top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what I'm missing, but I have the following Project structure:

```
Project
|audio_input
|output_files
|audio_classifier
||________________
                 |__init__.py
                 |base.py
                 |preprocessing
                 ||_____________
                                |__init__.py
                                |base.py
                                |input_preparation.py
                                |_feature_extraction.py
                 |classification
                 |______________
                                |__init__.py
                                |classifier_gpu_enabled.py
                                |_nn_architectures.py   
|docs
|examples
|tests
|README
|req.txt
|setup.py
```

`audio_classifier` is my Source Root, and base.py contents are:

```py
import sys
import os

print(sys.path)
print(__name__, __package__)

from audio_classifier.preprocessing.input_preparation import InputPreparation
```

I got two situations:

1. **Absolute import**: as I run `python -m base` in the audio_classifier folder I get the following error:
   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audio_classifier'`
   but it really confuses me, since I do already have an `__init__.py` on the top-level package. Shouldn't it be recognized?

`sys.path` contains the path ['/home/$USER/Project/audio_classifier', ...], shouldn't it be working using absolute import then?
And indeed `__package__` is empty.

2. **Relative Import**: Replacing `from audio_classifier.preprocessing.input_preparation import InputPreparation` for `from .preprocessing.input_preparation import InputPreparation` now I get the following error:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
which has the same problem root of python not identifying my top-level package as a package.

Notes: The first option actually works when running base.py using PyCharm. But the Source Root, environment and path are the same I'm running on my terminal. I must be missing something really important here.

I am trying to get the grasp of how huge libraries as numpy and librosa organize their repositories and trying to bring this concept to my own repo, but copying their approach got me these errors which I really can't get around at the moment.

Thank you in advance, folks.

EDIT1:
`PYTHONPATH: ['', '$HOME/.conda/envs/ac/lib/python37.zip', '$HOME/.conda/envs/ac/lib/python3.7', '$HOME/.conda/envs/ac/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '$HOME/.conda/envs/ac/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`

Comment: What does your PYTHONPATH look like?

Comment: Updated the question to contain $PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

- Your "source root" (in PyCharm terms) should be where your setup.py etc. are (i.e. `Project/` in your diagram). This is where you'll put all of your packages. (Some repositories have an additional `src/` directory, but let's not think about that now.)
- `Project/audio_classifier` should **not** be in `sys.path`, if you expect to be able to import things with `from audio_classifier...` without headache. Only `Project` should.

Here's a trivial example:

```sh
$ mkdir ac  # create a package directory
$ touch ac/__init__.py  # create the package init file so it's a package
$ echo 'from .foo import baz' > ac/base.py  # create a module in the package
$ mkdir ac/foo  # create a subpackage
$ echo 'baz = 8' > ac/foo/__init__.py  # create a package init file in the subpackage
$ echo -e 'from .base import baz\nprint(baz)' > ac/__main__.py  # create a __main__ file that can be run with `-m`
$ python -m ac
8
$
```

The structure looks like

```sh
$ tree -I '*.pyc'
.
└── ac
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── base.py
    └── foo
        └── __init__.py
```

and things work interactively too:

```py
>>> import ac
>>> import ac.base
>>> import ac.foo as f
>>> f.baz
8
>>> ac.base.baz
8
```

Comment: Thank you for answering AKX. Doesn't it go against what the Hitchhiker's guide explains? In terms of Project structure it really doesn't look like a wise choice. I'd much prefer maintaining this structure as it is and isolate tests, static resources, input, outputs, etc. They all don't belong to the root namespace in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I really want to keep the project structure as it is, as a personal choice. So @AKX gave me some precious resources to dig deeper.

I kept trying to tackle the issue, and found out my mistake: I was trying to invoke the package from inside of itself. So, I figured I had two options:

1. In my examples folder I wrote a script to consume my audio_classifier as a package using ```import audio_classifier...```
2. I did some argparsing to use the package as a CLI tool. The entry point  when running the package as ```python -m audio_classifier args --flags``` is \_\_main\_\_.py.

Comment: For sake of completion if someone is having the same problem I had: Since in my project, examples dir is one level down in relation to the root of the working directory, you should include it in your $PYTHONPATH: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))`.

Comment: You really, really, _really_ don't want to be modifying `sys.path` if you can avoid it, to, well, avoid a number of headaches down the road.